# How to test if a certain ad network is filling in an ad iframe on my webpage?

Tags: java, ruby, selenium, automated-tests, watir

I am still a wobbly young colt in the Automated Test Script world, so bear with me. I know enough to write simple scripts to fill out web forms or test if basic page elements exist in Watir or Selenium. I also have basic OOP skills in a couple different languages(just have to look up syntax on google but the ideology is there).

At any rate, let's say I have a website that has a few ad iframes that multiple ad feeds that are daisy chained together can fill on(if my top paying feed doesn't fill, it passes it on to the next in line). I have an ad feed that rarely fills, I want to write a script that will, at minimum, tell me if that ad feed fills at all - like a True/False Pass/Fail kind of deal.

What should I look for/search for? I am not really sure what to ask so it is hard to find stuff to read up on.
I imagine I would go into the iframe(browser.iframe?) but after that I am not sure how to sniff web traffic. Typically in my manual testing I open debugger and look under the resources to see the ad chain, or look in the network tab to see if there was a call made in the first place. All I am missing is that gap between finding the iframe on the page and seeing what is filling it.

Comment: It would probably help to share what the HTML looks like when the ad feed is filled as well as when it is not filled. I would guess you want to be looking for a specific element.

Comment: it is an iframe with the src="ad network X", when it doesnt fill there is a healthy hunk of js that tells me it has no ad then I make another call out to the next in line. So I guess what you are saying is look for s specific iframe with src=%specific ad chain call%?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely look for specific element or iframe, else you think that by seeing network request will help you then its better to use a proxy like browsermobproxy, start a session using selenium webdriver and proxy server, capture log for a session which is in json format and then you can look for desired format of url.